# marginal revenue and marginal cost and the relationship to profit

Tags: derivatives

now the profit, p(x) = revenue(r(x)) - cost for manufacture (c(x)) is a universal truth. If it's negative means it's just a lost and not profit.

The profit should be maximum when p'(x) = 0. As can be seen:
[image]
but, what if the function for r(x) and c(x) were such, even though it's highly impossible in real life the function exists;
[image]

Would this ***universal relationship*** not hold? What could the possible flaw in the logic be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understand your question correctly. $p(x)=r(x)-c(x)$. You make a profit if your revenue is more than the cost as you mentioned. Now If you have to maximize profit, first you need to find the critical point by letting $p'(x)=0$. In other words critical point is the point at which marginal cost $c'(x)$ equals marginal revenue $r'(x)$. If for this $x$, if you find that $r''(x)<c''(x)$, only then your profit will be maximized. In short, the "universal relation" will always hold.

Comment: I am confused on one point though. Profit is maximum when c(x) is minimum and r(x) is maximum, In other words the difference in r(x) and c(x) must be the highest . This is what r'(x) = c'(x) gives. In the second graph I have illustrated this. The difference is maximum yet the derivative is not equal.

Comment: above you have mentioned that r''(x) < c"(x) still would only imply that the revenue is decreasing in relation with the cost, which is directly given by the graph itself.

Comment: As you mentioned "the difference in $r(x)$ and $c(x)$ must be the highest".. This happens only if $r''(x)<c''(x)$ which in turn (for max profit) must happen for that $x$ for which $p'(x)=0$. Actually I studied all these in my $+2$. I just shared with you whatever I could recollect.

Comment: well, I don't know, what you say about r''(x) < c''(x) is true but r'(x) being equal to c'(x) isn't being logically sensible _from the second illustration above_